# mapbox - how to generate a random coordinate inside a polygon

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I've seen the leaflet plugin for mapbox which finds the polygon within which a specific point / coordinate lies, but how would I do the opposite - generate a random point / coordinate within a specific polygon?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Turf](http://turfjs.org)'s [Point on Surface](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_point-on-surface.html) method to generate a random point:

> Takes a feature and returns a Point guaranteed to be on the surface of the feature.

To check if a point is contained within a polygon you can use the [Inside](http://turfjs.org/static/docs/module-turf_inside.html) method:

> Takes a Point and a Polygon or MultiPolygon and determines if the point resides inside the polygon. The polygon can be convex or concave. The function accounts for holes.

Comment: thanks - I did this using a combination of a browserified version of https://github.com/mapbox/geojson-random and https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/point-in-polygon/, but it'd be interesting to do a benchmark and see which is faster

Comment: For future readers - it seems that it was renamed to PointOnFeature (see https://www.npmjs.com/package/@turf/point-on-surface, and https://www.npmjs.com/package/@turf/point-on-feature) but it *does not* return a random point on that feature - looking at the code, it always returns either the centroid of the given feature or the point closest to it if it is not in the feature (https://github.com/Turfjs/turf/blob/master/packages/turf-point-on-feature/index.js).

Comment: turf PointOnFeature doesn't generates random point, it generates some point with the fixed coordinates inside the feature. Each next call returns the same point.